# Os template failed for creation , but works good with rebuild ONLY

Tags: linux, hyper-v, openvz, templates

i made a cPanel os template with os centos , when i create new Openvz vps from HyperVm control panel it shows failed and the error message way too long , i will post some lines from the error :-

```
VM creation has failed. Reason: tar ././usr/share/doc/httpd-2.2.3/CHANGES Wrote only 6144 of 10240 bytes tar Skipping to next header tar ././usr/share/doc/httpd-2.2.3/LICENSE Cannot write Disk quota exceeded tar Skipping to next header tar ././usr/share/doc/httpd-2.2.3/migration.html Cannot write Disk quota exceeded tar Skipping to next header tar Archive contains obsolescent base-64 headers tar ././usr/share/doc/flex-2.5.4a/README Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/python-2.4.3 Cannot mkdir Disk quota exceeded tar ././usr/share/doc/python-2.4.3/LICENSE Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/python-2.4.3/README Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gtk2-2.10.4 Cannot mkdir Disk quota exceeded tar ././usr/share/doc/gtk2-2.10.4/COPYING Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gtk2-2.10.4/NEWS Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gtk2-2.10.4/AUTHORS Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gtk2-2.10.4/README Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gtk2-2.10.4/ChangeLog Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/initscripts-8.45.30 Cannot mkdir Disk quota exceeded tar ././usr/share/doc/initscripts-8.45.30/ipv6-6to4.howto Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/initscripts-8.45.30/sysvinitfiles Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/initscripts-8.45.30/changes.ipv6 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/initscripts-8.45.30/ipv6-tunnel.howto Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/initscripts-8.45.30/sysconfig.txt Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/initscripts-8.45.30/static-routes-ipv6 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/initscripts-8.45.30/ChangeLog Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2 Cannot mkdir Disk quota exceeded tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-1994.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-1997.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-2004.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-2002.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-1998.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog.gomp.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-1999.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-1993.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-1996.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-2003.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory tar ././usr/share/doc/gcc-c++-4.1.2/ChangeLog-2001.bz2 Cannot open No such file or directory
```

but if i create a openvz vps with default os template which is **centos-5-i386-afull** and rebuild it with custom os template which is cpanel centos os it will be rebuild well

the **Question** is : how could i **DIRECTLY** create the vps with the custom os template i made

NOTE :
1- i have enough space in the Node
2- custom os template size is 2546 MB

i hope someone will help me regard this issue

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a Disk Quota issue. 
(see the error message - )

> "Disk quota exceeded "

Begin by making sure you have enough room on the systems - as well as enough room on the VPS your building

As nutty as it sounds - it could be taxing out your tmp bin during the build...